# How to mirror the Form without mirroring the Title Bar (RightToLeftLayout) in WinForms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, designer

I try to mirror the Form. so I enabled the both properties. `RightToLeft` and `RightToLeftLayout`.
But the title bar is mirrored also.

What I try to do is override `CreateParams` in the following way inside CustomForm class:

```
public class CustomiForm : Form
{
    const int WS_EX_LAYOUTRTL = 0x400000;
    const int WS_EX_NOINHERITLAYOUT = 0x100000;
    private bool rightToLeftLayout = false;

    protected override CreateParams CreateParams
    {
        get
        {
            CreateParams CP;
            CP = base.CreateParams;
            if (this.RightToLeft == RightToLeft.Yes)
                 CP.ExStyle = CP.ExStyle | WS_EX_LAYOUTRTL | WS_EX_NOINHERITLAYOUT;
            return CP;
        }
   }
}
```

The result now is same the Title Bar is mirrored:

[image: See Image]

Comment: Can't you create a RTL panel and then put all the controls in it?

Comment: Keep the default values of the Form's Rtl & RtlLayout properties. Create a custom `Panel` or `UserControl` or `ContainerControl` and move your code snippet (the `CreateParams` property override part) to it. Build and drop instance, dock fill the custom container, add some controls, and set the Rtl property of the custom control to `Yes` to mirror the client area. Again, don't touch the RTL properties of the Form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to do such thing in WinForms.
**The best thing is to use normal Form.RightToLeft and RightToLeftLayout.**

Answer (score 1):

You can try to put all the controls you want to mirror into one seperate panel and just apply those properties to this newly created panel

Comment: I know that i can put controls inside a panel/container and override CreateParams. But I need to override the OS level itself. override something in The Form class itself. if you have any please inform.